# Azure AD B2C - Clean up URL

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Is there anyway currently as it stands to clean up a url so it would only contain the following:
"subdomain.contoso.com" without all the query parameters at the end of it.

Currently on my domain setup I have it as "login.contoso.com" this works fine however it requires all the rest of the following query parameters after the initial domain to be able to work.

Such as "https://login.contoso.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1a_signup_signin/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?......"

Where we want it as: "https://login.contoso.com"

Is there some guide that points out how we could get this to work without the query parameters being there. As we followed this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-domain?pivots=b2c-user-flow

Answer (score 0):

As I understand that you want to have the signup/sign-in URL shortened to domain.com/login. This is only possible if the application handles the signup/sign-in process without using an IDP such as B2C for this purpose. Hence its not possible to customize/hide the parameters within the B2C url, that is how OpenId Connect protocol works.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/759791/is-it-possible-to-get-a-short-url-for-the-the-sign.html